# Going through the same logic by order

Tags: python, loops

I have a piece of code as below:

```
a = df[['col1', 'col2_1', 'col2_2', 'col2_3', 'col3]]
a_indices = np.argmax(a.ne(0).values, axis=1)
a_df = pd.DataFrame(a.values[np.arange(len(a)), a_indices])

b = df[['col2_1', 'col2_2', 'col2_3', 'col3', 'col1]]
b_indices = np.argmax(b.ne(0).values, axis=1)
b_df = pd.DataFrame(b.values[np.arange(len(b)), b_indices])
```

....

This code is repetitive, and I am hoping to loop them through. The idea is to have all the combination of different orders of cal_1, col_2(col2_1, col2_2, col2_3), and col_3. The return should be a combined dataframe of a_df and b_df.

Note: col2_1, col2_2, and col2_3 can have different orders, but they always stay next to each other. Anyways to make this piece of code simpler?

Answer (score 0):

What you can do so far is to define the **maximum** number of iterations to loop on. So far you have 5 columns to loop on.

```py
list_columns = ['col1', 'col2_1', 'col2_2', 'col2_3', 'col3']
print(len(list_columns)) # returns 5
```

Then, you can define your column names based on what you want to put in your dataframe. Suppose you have 5 iterations to make. Your column names would be `['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E']`. This is the `column` argument of your dataframe. An easier way to concatenate several columns at once is to create a **dictionary** first, with **each column name being the key** and each of them having **a list the same size as a value**.

```py
list_columns = ['col1', 'col2_1', 'col2_2', 'col2_3', 'col3']
new_columns = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E']

# Use a dictionary comprehension in my case
data_dict = {column: [] for column in new_columns}

n = 50 # Assume the number of loops is arbitrary there

for i in range(n):
    for col in new_columns:
        # do something
        data_dict[col].append(something)
```

In your case it looks like you can directly operate on the lists by providing a NumPy array instead. Therefore:

```py
list_cols = ['col1', 'col2_1', 'col2_2', 'col2_3', 'col3']
new_cols = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E']
data_df = {}

for i, (col, new_col) in enumerate(zip(list_cols, new_cols)):
  print(col, list_cols[0:i] + list_cols[i+1:])
  temp_df = df[[col] + list_cols[0:i] + list_cols[i+1:]]
  temp_indices = np.argmax(temp_df.ne(0).values, axis=1) 
  data_df[new_col] = b.values[np.arange(len(temp_df)), temp_indices]

final_df = pd.DataFrame(data_df)
```

What I basically did was a double unpacking combining `enumerate` to get the index and `zip` to get your final result. The columns are there selected and placed before the rest of the list in no particular order.